# SSH: key rejected

Tags: 16.04, ssh, putty, sshd

I set up an sshd passwordless server, and I got the following problem:

If I log into my 16.04 box **physically**, I can, afterwards, log in on it via ssh.

If I don't do it (e.g. remotely reboot my machine) I cannot log in on it via ssh, because it rejects my key.

Suggestions?

NOTE: Here is my configuration file:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 1907
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no
#
# Compression
Compression yes
```

Comment: Is the error definitely `rejected`? Not `refused`?

Comment: I don't know right now, since my windows laptop is in my car. But It was rejected almost surely.

Comment: Are you SSH in as `root` and is there any chance you change the `PermitRootLogin` to `no` while configuring the config?

Comment: Could be a number of problems. Are you still using PuTTy ? Or did you change to ssh ? What command and what user did you use ? output of `ssh -vvv user@server` , post the exact ssh command you ran with the -vvv option.

Comment: Guys, that's odd. I sent someone to check. The machine was up and running, however he rebooted the machine locally, then put it in standby. I woke up it (wol) and was able to ssh on it. Then I rebooted it via ssh (shutdown -r), and again it rejects my key now. It seems it rejects the key just when I reboot it remotely, so I wonder how a reboot issued locally differs from a reboot issued remotely!
I'm using putty (bitvise, indeed), and don't have a command line ssh client here on windows. I don't ssh as root (it's disabled) and didn't change any key, neither public nor private.

Comment: That sound very strange. I normally run `reboot` instead of `shutdown -r`, you could test it. But could you also post the your `sshd_config` file for us please?

Comment: Not sure but it takes a bit of time for ssh to come online after a reboot.

Comment: Sure. I edited my post and added config. No, I would exclude sshd delays in coming online since I tried hours afterwards...

Comment: I edited and reframed my problem, hoping someone has had the same experience and can provide a solution.

Comment: Could your home directory be encrypted?

Comment: Hell, it is indeed. I didn't think of it. Thanks. Is there any workaround?